# Want to post json to a url, I have the json as a string

Tags: ruby, json

I have a json representation in a string variable, and i want to use ruby to post this to a url.

SO I have this so far:

```
require 'json'
require 'net/http'

uri = URI.parse("http://www.example.com/post/here")
```

My json as a string looks like:

```
{"id":-1,"userId":1,"name":"some-test","createdAt":1356665463287}
```

How can I take that string and load that into a ruby object and then post it?

Comment: Why would you post it as a Ruby object and not just a string? Setting the `Content-Type` header to be `application/json` should make the server on the other end know that the request is being made with JSON.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The Net:HTTP docs just aren't worth the effort, in my opinion. You'll probably find [Faraday](https://github.com/lostisland/faraday) a bit nicer:

```
require 'faraday'
conn = Faraday.new(:url => 'http://www.example.com')

# post payload as JSON instead of "www-form-urlencoded" encoding:
conn.post do |req|
  req.url '/post/here'
  req.headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/json'
  req.body = '{"id":-1,"userId":1,"name":"some-test","createdAt":1356665463287}'
end
```

Comment: `conn.post` will return a Faraday::Response object